# Гаишник - как писать?

Tags: орфография

Писать это слово в кавычках или без? Большими ли писать три первые буквы (ГАИшник)? Нужен ли дефис?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Суффиксальные производные от звуковых аббревиатур пишутся только
>   строчными буквами, напр.: *ооновский, тассовский, мидовский,
>   антиспидовый, омоновец, **гаишник***.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95
(Справочник Лопатина, §205)